# Normal Glass but behaving like mirror?

Tags: blender-internal-render-engine

[image]

the light source is hdri and light portal in the windows.
i use camera transparency setting and glass transparency. but some of the windows glass behave like a mirror.

Comment: Well, that's how glass works... If you want transparency without reflection, you can use a Transparent BSDF shader.

Comment: Hello and welcome :). Real glass will actually act as a mirror under a shallow viewing angle. In your case, it doesn't look too realistic so there might be other issues. You can [share your file](https://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/), so others can take a look.

Comment: Try adding a glass with a transparency mix shader, and set the IOR to a low level.

Answer (score 0):

I found a bit of a workaround to this issue. It's not ideal for every situation but if you lower your alpha it can solve this issue.

Comment: Hi, thanks for the post. This site is not a regular forum, answers should be substantial and thoroughly explain the solution and required workflow. One liners and short tips rarely make for a good answer. If you can [edit] your post and provide some more details about the procedure and why it works feel free to restore it, otherwise it may be deleted or converted into a comment. Perhaps add a few [images](https://blender.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/963) illustrating the workflow and final results. See [How do I write a good answer?](https://blender.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-answer)